# How to embed a keystore certificate only during runtime from classpath?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I have an application that should connect to a `https` webservice.

The webservice offers a zip file containing the following 3 files: *.crt, *.csr, *.key

Question: can I place them into the `classpath` of the application `jar`, and then load the cert only on startup (maybe in an own keystore/truststore that is is created on the fly)?

Or do I necessairly have to intall them into the java `keystore` on each machine, before I can use the my app client?

My preferred way would be to not having install them to the local java keystore, but load them on the fly during application startup.

Comment: It should be possible to load the keystore at runtime, at least the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) contain examples on this.

Comment: You need to get rid  of the CLASSPATH aspect of this notion. You need to put the certificate material into the file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it's actually possible, also from classpath:

```
// pass a p12 or pfx file (file may be on classpath also)
public void initSSL(String keyStoreFile, String pass) {
    InputStream keyStoreStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyStoreFile);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, keyPassword.toCharArray());
    kmf.init(keyStore, keyPassword.toCharArray());

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);

    // init the trust manager factory by read certificates
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustStore);

    // 3. init the SSLContext using kmf and tmf above
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
}
```

Comment: There is no classpath in use here. You've located the file in the file system. Period.

Comment: Sorry, copypast issue, corrected the `InputStream` to classpath stream.